# How to extract data present between 2 matched items(from a csv) inside a text file?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, loops, pattern-matching

```
Quetiapine fumarate Drug substance  This document
Povidone    Binder  USP
This line doesn't contain any medicine name.
Dibasic calcium phosphate dihydrate Diluent USP is not present in the csv
Lactose monohydrate Diluent USNF
Magnesium stearate  Lubricant   USNF
```

The above represents sample data from a .txt file:

I have a list of medicine name which I want to match inside the .txt file and extract all the data that is present between 2 medicines.(Example of medicines from the csv file are `'Quetiapine fumarate', 'Povidone', 'Magnesium stearate', 'Lactose monohydrate'  etc etc.)`

substancecopy.csv is the file containing list of all medicines which I have used in my code below.

I want to iterate each line of my text file and create groups from one medicine to another.

Example output:

```
['Quetiapine fumarate   Drug substance  This document'],
['Povidone  Binder  USP'],
['Lactose monohydrate   Diluent USNF'],
['Magnesium stearate    Lubricant   USNF']
```

Given that `'Quetiapine fumarate'`, `'Povidone'`, `'Lactose monohydrate`', `'Magnesium stearate'` are present in my csv list of substances.

Can someone please help me with the same to do this in Python?

Attempt till now:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
file = open(r'C:\Users\substancecopy.csv', 'r')
oo=csv.reader(file)
allsub = []
for line in oo:
    allsub.append(line)

flat_list = [item for sublist in allsub for item in sublist]    


def extract(filename):
    file=open(filename,encoding='utf-8')
    file=file.read()

    n=[]
    for x in flat_list:
        my_regex = r"^\s?" + re.escape(x)
        #my_regex_new = r"\b" + re.escape(my_regex) + r"\b"
        if re.search(my_regex,file,flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE):
            n.append(x)


    n.sort()
    return n
```

I need to capture all the text from one medicine to another as shown in Example Output which is not happening with this piece of code

Comment: Are you wanting to gather all text between two points, or just rows with medicine names? Your example output shows only containing names, however your question seems towards all text between two medicine names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting data from a txt file present between two matched items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940571/extracting-data-from-a-txt-file-present-between-two-matched-items).

Answer (score 0):

The following approach looks to work well on small data sets. However i would assume over large data sets it may not be efficient, and there could be better ways to perform this.

I have taken the approach based on the idea of your question, that all data must be stored between medication names. If you want to only store lines where medications are matched you can do the following;

```
result = [[row.strip()] for row in data for med in meds if med in row]

#[['Quetiapine fumarate Drug substance  This document'], ['Povidone    Binder  USP'], ['Lactose monohydrate Diluent USNF'], ['Magnesium stearate  Lubricant   USNF']]
```

I loaded the medication names into a list which you may have to adjust to your `csv`.

```
meds = ['Quetiapine fumarate', 'Povidone', 'Magnesium stearate', 'Lactose monohydrate']

with open('1.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

result = [] # Empty list to store our findings

for idx, row in enumerate(data): # Get index and value of each line in the text file
    count = 0 # Set a counter for each row, this is to determine if there are no matches

    for med in meds:
        if med in row and med not in data[idx-1]: # If medication is matched and the same medication is not found in the previous row
            result.append([row.strip()])
        else: # No match found on this medication, increase counter
            count += 1

    if count == len(meds): # If count == total medication, declare no match and append to previous row
        result[-1].append(row.strip())



for i in result:
    print(i)

#['Quetiapine fumarate Drug substance  This document']
#['Povidone    Binder  USP', 'Povidone new line', "This line doesn't contain any medicine name.", 'Dibasic calcium phosphate dihydrate Diluent USP is not present in the csv']
#['Lactose monohydrate Diluent USNF']
#['Magnesium stearate  Lubricant   USNF']
```

I added `Povidone new line` to the test file to demonstrate that if the same medication name is found within the same line, it is appended to the last result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your ouput, I see these lines `This line doesn't contain any medicine name,
Dibasic calcium phosphate dihydrate Diluent USP is not present in the csv` which shouldn't be present in the output because there are no matching medicine names in these lines. So the output should be exactly how I mentioned my example output without these additional lines from the file. Can you help now?

Comment: Yes, the top section of code does that. `result = [[row.strip()] for row in data for med in meds if med in row]`